# Setting the product version for a WiX project via MSBuild on a Jekins server. What's wrong here?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jenkins, msbuild, wix

I'm trying to pass a dynamically determined version of a product to a WiX project via a call to an MSBuild project from Jenkins.

For starters, I don't think the problem is actually in Jenkins, since I can't get what I'm trying to do to work when running MSBuild from the VS2013 command prompt with a version hardcoded into our MSBuild project file.

The MSBuild project file is set to run from Jenkins with the following parameters:  `/p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x86" /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true`

The MSBuild project looks as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\.build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets"/>

  <!-- Version Number -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Major>0</Major>
    <Minor>9</Minor>
    <Build>1</Build>
    <!--Jenkins sets BUILD_NUMBER -->
    <Revision>$(BUILD_NUMBER)</Revision>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_LatestBuild\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Version">
    <Message Text="Version: $(Version)"/>
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS" 
                  OutputFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs"
                  AssemblyVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)"
                  AssemblyConfiguration="$(Configuration)"
                  Condition="$(Revision) != '' " />
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS" 
                  OutputFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" 
                  AssemblyVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).*"                   
                  AssemblyConfiguration="$(Configuration)"
                  Condition="$(Revision) == '' " />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ZipSourceFiles Include="$(OutputPath)\Installer\**\*.*" Exclude="$(OutputPath)\Installer\**\*.zip;$(OutputPath)\Installer\**\*.wixpdb" />
      <ZipFile Include="ProductName v$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision).zip"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Zip: $(OutputPath)\*.*"/>
    <Zip Files="@(ZipSourceFiles)" WorkingDirectory="$(OutputPath)\Installer\" ZipFileName="@(ZipFile)" ParallelCompression="false" />
    <Message Text="Copying archive..."/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ZipFile)" DestinationFolder="\\serverName\Projects\Active\ProductName\Builds" />
  </Target>

  <!-- Projects to Build -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.sln">
      <Properties>Configuration=$(Configuration)</Properties>
    </ProjectFiles>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Version">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectFiles)"  />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="BuildInstaller">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\ProductName.Installation\ProductName.Installation.wixproj" Properties="ProductVersion=$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <CallTarget Targets="Compile;BuildInstaller;AfterBuild" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The WiX project file is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>e5232ce4-4412-4e41-9157-8ab1a36960b0</ProjectGuid>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <OutputName>DicksonWare.Installation</OutputName>
    <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    <ProductVersion Condition=" '$(ProductVersion)' == '' ">2.0.0.0</ProductVersion>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>..\_LatestBuild\Installer\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>Debug;BuildVersion=$(ProductVersion)</DefineConstants>
    <SuppressIces>ICE69</SuppressIces>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>..\_LatestBuild\Installer\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>BuildVersion=$(ProductVersion)</DefineConstants>
    <SuppressIces>ICE69;ICE61</SuppressIces>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Product.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
      <HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
  <!--
  To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
  Other similar extension points exist, see Wix.targets.
  -->
  <!--
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Then in the .wxs file to set the version I simply do `Version="$(var.BuildVersion)"`

However, when Jenkins calls MSBuild on the build project or I manually type `msbuild build.proj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x86" /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true /p:BUILD_NUMBER=23` and then run the .msi file created, the version given in the .msi file is always the `2.0.0.0` default I've set in the .wixproj file.

I'm pretty sure it's not the actual call to MSBuild that's the problem, since replacing the BuildInstaller task with `<MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\ProductName.Installation\ProductName.Installation.wixproj" Properties="ProductVersion=1.2.3.4" />` still has the same problem.

From what I've been able to find by searching around, what I'm doing *should* be fine. But it's obviously not. Any ideas on what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know about Jenkins but the msbuild/wxs looks right.  Similar to my answer below which I know works called from TFS and from a .BAT file.

Comment: I am unable to build .sln solution (containing wix project in it) from ms build in jenkins, it says .wixproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built. How do I fix this >

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at:

http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Installer/IsWiX/IsWiX.wixproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- If MSIProductVersion not passed in, try to get it fom TFBuild Environments-->
    <MSIProductVersion Condition=" '$(MSIProductVersion)' == '' ">$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER), "\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+"))</MSIProductVersion>
    <!-- If we still don't have a value, default to 1.0.0 for developer builds -->
    <MSIProductVersion Condition=" '$(MSIProductVersion)' == '' ">1.0.0</MSIProductVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <DefineConstants>WiXProductVersion=$(MSIProductVersion)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Installer/IsWiX/IsWiX.wxs

```
<Product Id="*" Name="IsWiX" Language="1033" Version="$(var.WiXProductVersion)"
           Manufacturer="ISWIX LLC" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
```

Pass `/p:MSIProductVersion=1.2.3.4` when you call MSBuild. Alternatively you can set the environment variable TF_BUILD_NUMBER as this is how TFS does it these days.

Comment: The first issue with passing in the version as a parameter is that I don't know how to get the build number from Jenkins that way. (I suppose the build number is not strictly necessary, so that's not a showstopper.)

The other (and main) issue is that the Jenkins parameters aren't in any version control like the msbuild project is. I'd prefer it if it could be grabbed from the build project if at all possible. (If it's not, I guess I'm stuck with doing it that way then.)

Comment: I'd start with a simple HelloWorld.proj that does a Message Text and practice with that first.  I helped a customer set a Hudson build up once and I don't recall it being problematic.

Comment: Did you see my edit above? I accidentally posted before my statement was complete.

Comment: This is perfect. I don't know why it's so difficult to generate and pass compile-time variables from TFS/Jenkins, to MSBuild, and then consume them in WIX.

Comment: I copied and pasted /p:MSIProductVerison=1.2.3.4 and spent the last hour trying to figure why the product version was not being passed to my installer. There is a typo and stackoverflow won't let me try to fix it. It should be 

/p:MSIProductVersion=1.2.3.4

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I've fixed the type.  Wish I could give you that hour back.

Comment: @billy btw this answer is 8 years old.  We've moved to GitHub https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials